# How to remove a parent view - android

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android:

Given a View from an onTouchEvent, how can I remove the View and its parent?

I have a LinearLayout in which I have a View. Clicking on the View creates a sub-layout inside of the LinearLayout. That sub-layout needs its own onTouchListeners so I cannot attach an onTouchListener to the parent LinearLayout because that will always block onTouchListeners to my sub-layout.

Therefore, I need a means to remove the parent layout given its child layout. I can already remove child layouts from their parents.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you know how to remove child views from a parent, stick with what you know ;)
The idea is to elevate to a position in the view tree where you can remove your parent view as a child. How do you do that? Easy, get the grandparent view of your view and remove your parent view from the grandparent.

```
((ViewGroup)view.getParent().getParent()).removeView((ViewGroup)view.getParent());
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks.
Note: I lost count of my getParent()s in there and found that your code works with the one edit of another recast to ViewGroup
((ViewGroup)v.getParent().getParent()).removeView((ViewGroup)v.getParent());

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you! I updated my answer to reflect your changes

Comment: @thomaspsk I want to add Images daynamically to my linearlayout that i have done. later I remove some of images from layout. then I want to restore it at its own position from where I have removed. means I want to add images without removing child's parent can you please hlep me ?

Comment: @thomaspsk can you help me please. i am trying to show a fragment in relative layout on a button click. but its showing error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." how to solve this?